# Delegate to replace repeating code

Tags: c#, delegates, checkbox

I have 10 check boxes in a group box.  The top check box labeled "All" checks the other 9 check boxes when checked is true for "All"

In the other 9 checkboxes, I have essentially the same code.  Here is a sample for two of the check boxes:

```
private void ckDal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ckDal.Checked == false)
            ckAll.Checked = false;
    }

    private void ckHou_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ckHou.Checked == false)
            ckAll.Checked = false;
    }
```

I hate repeating the same code.  How would I create a delegate to accomplish the above with just one event method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use single `Click` event handler for all CheckBoxes. Actual CheckBox, which raised the event, will be available from `sender` parameter. Just cast it to CheckBox type:

```
private void ck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
        ckAll.Checked = false;
}
```

Also you don't need to compare boolean values with true/false - you can use them directly in `if` statement.

*BTW* you should also verify case when all CheckBoxes were checked, and set `ckAll.Checked = true` in that case.

Comment: Thank you regarding the case when all Checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void CheckBoxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (!((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
        ckAll.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the post was helpful