# Repeat the method or one delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, delegates, dry

When a variable is repeated several times, we use a local variable to 'solve' this. Of course, there are times to repeat method (calls) as well. For example when checking the application settings as shown below.

```
static T Get<T>(NHibernateSetting key, T defaultValue) {
  // Do something
}

void setApplicationSettings() {
    var logFileName = Settings.Get(Setting.LogFileName, "default.log");
    if (/* Do some check */)
        configuration.LogFile(logFileName);

    var adoNetBatchSize = Settings.Get<int?>(Setting.AdoNetBatchSize, null);
    if (adoNetBatchSize.HasValue)
        configuration.AdoNetBatchSize(adoNetBatchSize.Value);

    if (Settings.Get(Setting.UseReflectionOptimizer, true))
        configuration.UseReflectionOptimizer();

    if (Settings.Get(Setting.GenerateStatistics, false))
        configuration.Raw("generate_statistics", "true");
}
```

Repeating the method isn't very [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) so could a delegate help here? At first, I thought to put it into a `Func<in T1, in T2, out T3>` like below. Performance-wise this would be equal to the original native calling of the method, right?

```
var typedGetter = new Func<NHibernateSetting, String, String>(Settings.Get);
```

Then I bumped into a next problem since `String` is not the only `T` that is being used so I'd be saddled by typing out all needed types. I tried the following but it didn't work. Any infomation about how this can be solved?

```
var genericGetter = new Func<NHibernateSetting, T, T>(Settings.Get);
```

**Duplicates.** The question [Delegate to replace repeating code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031490/delegate-to-replace-repeating-code) might seem like a duplicate question but it's different nonetheless, if only the outcome.

Comment: For the people who downvote, please post the reason and/or (constructive) feedback to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be just me, but I don't think this violates the DRY principle. You're calling a method to get a setting based on name and default value. Even if you replace it with a delegate or anything, you're still going to call the delegate - you're replacing a one-line call with another one-line call.

Just out of curiosity, why isn't the Setting.UseReflectionOptimizer a property with a getter that calls Settings.Get, and a setter that calls Settings.Set or whatever?

Comment: DRY: Perhaps you're right about the DRY part though with a delegate we only need to change the delegate when the function is changed (and you don't have automatic refactoring). **I still want a generic Func, is it possible?**

About `Setting.UseReflectionOptimizer`, that is a copy-paste error ;-) I edited my post after your comment

Comment: You could have a generic Func as a field of a generic static class, eg. static class Getter<T> { static Func<NHibernateSetting, T, T> GenericGetter; }.
The runtime will then create classes for all the various Ts on request.

Comment: I like the `GenericGetter` but it doesn't infer the type so you are **obliged** to specify the type.
P.S. You can surround your code with a grave ` to format it as code, it increases the readability of yours posts.

Comment: Yeah, to have automatic type inferrence, you'd have to have a method to return the field. But that pretty much brings you to where you started.
What about creating an extension method on NHibernateSetting? Instead of `Setting.Get`, you'd simply call `Setting.GenerateStatistics.Get(false)`.
P.S. Thanks for the code tip :)